# LSTM Many to one with multiple time steps for time series (multi class classification)

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm, multiclass-classification

I want to do a time series multi-class classification for fault detection and diagnosis with time-series sensor data set which contains a sequence of 50 records of normal data and sequences of another 50 records for each fault type. All together there are 3 types of data including normal condition. so the output will be a one hot encoded vector. And since there are three different data series collected for each condition, I have decided to go with 3 time steps which LSTM will take each condition as a one series that will be trained. Data set summery is 4 input features,3 class labels, and 150 samples.

This model currently gives me the output vector of possible class labels predicted for each samples i have provided in the predict function like below.

```
model.predict([[[6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5],[6.3, 2.76, 4.4, 1.3],[5.5, 3.8, 1.6, 0.5]]]).argmax(-1)
>>>array([[1, 1, 0]])
```

But here, considering all the four samples i have provided in predict function, is there any posibility for me to predict a one class label? This is possible when i reshape my train data to have only one time step. But i believe that using 3 time steps is ideal here since i have 3 types of sequences( 3 conditions). Please guide me on how to achieve this with LSTM.

Following is the current implementation i have done with multi time steps.

```
#load dataset
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv("chiller_plant.csv",header=None)
    dataset = dataframe.values
    X=dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
    Y=dataset[:,4]
```

```
# Encode the output variables
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(Y)
    # convert output variables into the numbers
    encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
    # Convert integers to dummy variables (one-hot encoded)
    dummy_Y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,dummy_Y,test_size=0.2) #20% is allocated for the testing
```

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(40, 3, 4)
y_train = y_train.reshape(40, 3, 3)
y_train.shape,X_train.shape
```

> ((40, 3, 3), (40, 3, 4))

```
 # Create the Neural Network Model
def create_nn_model():
#create sequential model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

```
model = create_nn_model()
model.summary()
```

```
> Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 3, 100)            42000     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 3, 100)            10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 3, 3)              303       
=================================================================
Total params: 52,403
Trainable params: 52,403
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=200,batch_size=5)
```

Comment: `return_sequences=False`

Comment: @10xAI but then it would just be feed forward without multi time steps right?

Comment: It will be multi-step in the LSTM layer. So, it will be SEQ-Vector instead of SEQ-SEQ

Comment: can you please explain that a little bit more? and isn't it suitable for me to go with 3 time steps as i have mentioned? the current output that i get calling the predict function has 3 elements at 3 time steps that model has predicted right? so if i go with multi time steps i have to get the last element of the one hot encoded vector that i get as output? ex >>>array([[1, 1, 0]]) here i have to get 0th class label as the predicted label?  can you please share as the answer so i can mark it as the answer ?

Comment: @10xAI I get the following error when changed to `return_sequences=False`                  `ValueError: Shapes (5, 3, 3) and (5, 3) are incompatible`

Comment: Yes, you will have to reshape `y_true` accordingly. `y_pred` is now (5,3) _i.e. one for each input. Earlier it was one for each step_.

Comment: If i reshape y_true , there will be no longer the multi time steps scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127375/discussion-between-10xai-and-sinfer).